# Use Excel to optimise KFC order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Don't laugh, but, from time to time, my friends and I host a multiple-course KFC dinner, and I have a spreadsheet to optimise the order. This is to make sure we order the right combination of 'bucket'-type items (i.e. SKUs that contain multiple pieces, often of different types):

1. to minimise leftover items
2. to reduce the total cost

[Here is the spreadsheet I currently use](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdnicv6l1xdl5ki/Colonel%27s%20Club.xlsx?dl=0), and here's a screenshot:

[image]

To use it, you first specify the number of participants in `A2`, and what you want each person to have in `E2:E6` (we're really only interested in the chicken, so 'sides' are treated as generic to simplify).

Here's the **manual part**, that I'd like to improve.

The next step is to look at the *ideal* totals for each item (`F2:F6`), and to try to set the right quantities (`H12:H20`) of the 'bucket'-type SKUs that I have recreated (`A11:G20`), so that the *output* totals (`H21:M21`) match the *ideal* totals (`F2:F6`).

The optimisation part is to get the *deltas* (`H22:M22`) as close to zero as possible, and to get the *total cost* (`N21`) as low as possible.

So, my question is: **is there a way to do this better?** I think Excel has some sort of Solver functionality, but I'm afraid I don't know how I'd go about even starting to use that, as my Excel skills are pretty rudimentary. Oh, and in case it makes a difference regarding functionality, I'm using Excel for Mac v16.37.

Any thoughts gratefully appreciated! :)

Comment: `I think Excel has some sort of Solver functionality` - it's even called [Solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040).

Comment: Thanks—I should have clarified that I had heard of Solver, but, like I said, my Excel skills aren't that great, so I was really hoping someone would be able to walk me through it...

Comment: You already did all the work, which is setting up the formulas for the model. Click the link, refer to the pictures, start Solver in your Excel, in the dialog specify that you want to set cell N21 to Min, by changing cells H12:H20, subject to the constraint that H12:H20 is >=0, and to the constraint that each person receives enough food - not sure which column that is. Then go to options and set to solve in integers, then solve.

Comment: Oh wow, that was much more straightforward than I thought it'd be. Thank you so much!! :D I'd mark your answer as correct but it's only a comment, so not sure if I can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't take any credit for this, but am happy to say that GSerg left me a couple of comments that pointed me in the right direction, and I now have [Solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) set up to organise my chicken parties!

Here are the parameters for anyone who is curious:
[image: Solver parameters]